# Custom font different across browsers (Safari/Chrome/Firefox)

Tags: css, browser, fonts, cross-browser, font-face

My custom font (Gilroy, purchased on myfonts) is having issues across browsers. The font is thicker and bigger in Chrome than on other browsers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The font size is the same, but your letters in Chrome are bolder than in Firefox. That's because you are importing your fonts wrong.

Currently you are using:

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: "Cobury Regular";
  src: url(https://cobury.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/03/3B2CCC_0_0.woff) format("woff");
  font-weight: 400;
  font-style: normal;
}
@font-face {
  font-family: "Cobury Bold";
  src: url(https://cobury.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/03/3B2CD0_0_0.woff) format("woff");
  font-weight: 400;
  font-style: normal;
}

... {
  font-family: "Cobury Regular";
}
... {
  font-family: "Cobury Bold";
}
```

But the correct way would be:

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: "Cobury";
  src: url(https://cobury.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/03/3B2CCC_0_0.woff) format("woff");
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
@font-face {
  font-family: "Cobury";
  src: url(https://cobury.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/03/3B2CD0_0_0.woff) format("woff");
  font-weight: bold;
  font-style: normal;
}

... {
  font-family: "Cobury";
  font-weight: normal;
}
... {
  font-family: "Cobury";
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

Always use font with their actual `font-weight`. Don't treat the same font with different weight and style like different fonts.

Your `.woff` font files have implemented meta tags inside, which telling the browser what thickness the letters have. If the provided `font-weight` in the import statement `@font-face` doesn't match with that, browsers will treat that differently, because there is no standard for that. (Chrome tries to handle the situation by adding a additional thickness to the already bold font, for whatever reason.)

**Edit:**
I'm seeing that you use `h1, .text-logo #logo { font-weight: 900; ...` in your CSS but you have never defined the font with the weight number `900`. Please use only the weights you have provided via `@font-face`. (With my suggestion it would be `normal` and `bold`)

Comment: you can use  `@font-face { font-weight: 500; ...` and `@font-face { font-weight: 900; ...` instead. That might be better. I don't know the actual weight of your Cobury Bold font. It might be 900 (=bolder), 800 or 700 (=bold).

Comment: I don't know. I can only tell you, that his is bad practice, because it can cause issues like that. For every combination of weight and style you want to use, there should be a matching entry defined by @font-face. That is the defined standard in CSS. Anything else can (and will) cause unpredictable behavior.